# C struct definition with initialization question

Tags: c

I saw this `struct` definition in an old Olden benchmark `perimeter`:

```
typedef struct quad_struct {
  Color color;
  ChildType childtype;

#ifndef TORONTO
  struct quad_struct *nw {50};
  struct quad_struct *ne {50};
  struct quad_struct *sw {50};
  struct quad_struct *se {50};
  struct quad_struct *parent {50};
#else
  struct quad_struct *nw;
  struct quad_struct *ne;
  struct quad_struct *sw;
  struct quad_struct *se;
  struct quad_struct *parent;
#endif

} quad_struct, *QuadTree;
```

(You can find the code at: https://github.com/llvm-mirror/test-suite/blob/master/MultiSource/Benchmarks/Olden/perimeter/perimeter.h#L22)

What does `struct quad_struct *nw {50};` do? It looks like initializing a pointer to a constant value.
I tried compiling this kind of code with modern compilers, e.g., llvm 10 or gcc 9, and I got compile error
`error: expected ';' at end of declaration list struct quad_struct *nw {50};`

Comment: You need to compile with the same flags as the project is doing. In particular, there's probably something like `-std=c99` or so in the.

Comment: In the makefile TORONTO is defined so the first part is not used. CPPFLAGS = -DTORONTO

Comment: I tried looking at the makefile to see if there was some obscure case I was missing, but TORONTO is unconditionally defined. I don't see a straightforward way of getting an answer short of leaving this up and hoping somebody recognizes that nonstandard syntax.

Comment: @PtitXav thanks for pointing this out. But my point of asking this question is to figure out what the syntax means instead of why it compiles in the benchmark suite.

Comment: @MadPhysicist just an FYI I tried `-std=c99` and still got compile error.

Comment: I didn't say to to `std=c99`. I said find out what they're using, which may look something like that.

Answer (score 0):

More information on the Olden benchmark here :
https://www.irisa.fr/caps/people/truong/M2COct99/Benchmarks/Olden/Welcome.html
Mainly :

> The Olden benchmarks were compiled to test the Olden C* compiler for the CM5